# Looking for Dashboard Shell Linux (Bash)

Tags: debian

I am looking for a small dashboard for Linux in the bash shell that I can configure freely. E.g. Fail2Ban blocks, uptime, running services, ClavAM findings, last login.

Can anyone recommend me a good project? Is there such a thing at all?